# Why does my paperjs app take so much CPU power and slow down?

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I have [this Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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). You can pilot the ship by using up to accelerate and left and right to rotate the ships orientation. (Although it doesn't always work on Sketch due to the inability to blur from the editor and so keypress events don't register in the canvas window)

Each frame it adds the point at the ship's current centroid to the full ship track. This all works fine and dandy. Problems set in after about 2 minutes or so - depending on your computer - of flying. Gradually the whole thing starts slowing down and the frame rate drops to visible levels. Initially I thought this is because each point needs to be stored in RAM and there are too many of them, but the tab's memory doesn't seem to go up noticeably. CPU usage does seem to rapidly rise to ~20% and generally stays there. Does anyone have an explanation or fix for this?

Comment: I don't understand fully what you're doing but it appears that you're either creating a new entity/line/graphic per frame tick to draw the line behind the ship.  Is that correct?  Are you adding a display entity per line segment?  Are you able to just draw to an existing layer.  Usually when I see something like this (e.g. blood splatter on floor from killed enemy in 2d top-down shooter), they paint addt. items to an existing canvas, not adding new display entities.  I'm just throwing ideas out there btw.

Comment: Have you used paperjs before? In paperjs you can create a path and then just add points to it, and it will display the entire path with all its points. They're not separate paths though, just points joined together. Paperjs takes care of rendering frames so that you don't need to worry about animatng movement. You can just specify what should change in each frame without redrawing the whole scene. I do create a new path but only when the ship goes outside the window's boundaries, otherwise there would be lines from the top of the screen where it disappeared to the bottom where it reappeared.

Comment: no, never used PaperJs before but done plenty of game programming to get the gist of the API.  Their API docs are really nice.  I may need to check this lib out for a game I'm working on.

Comment: Yeah the paperjs library is really really sweet. Very easy to use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I did a little reading up on this.  Your continuously adding to your `ship.path` in your frame tick callback.  Try limiting the maximum size of your path like so:

```
var MAX_SEGMENTS = 1000

ship.path.add(centroid(ship.shipPath));

function onFrame(event) {
    if (ship.path.length > MAX_SEGMENTS)
    {
        var d = ship.path.length - MAX_SEGMENTS
        ship.path.removeSegments(0, d)
    }
```

updated [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

Comment: just noticed this doesn't work if you're going off-screen and then moving to the opposite position.  That will be something you need to work into your logic for that.  In game development, you gotta watch your resources well.  Unless you're painting to a canvas where there is basically a set amount of pixels in the canvas and you're just coloring them, then using a display list type approach can get you in trouble if you're not careful

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that too. That I could work around. However the main problem now seems to be that the tab jut crashes completely and the console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_path' of undefined`

Comment: You can also use `path.simplify(tolerance)` to cut down the number of segments. If you simplify the path every 50 frames or so then add those points to a larger simplified path, you can get a much more memory-efficient segment array.

Comment: So I did consider that as an option - but memory doesn't seem to be the problem. The tab's memory doesn't go up at all. So the problem must be something else.. no?

Comment: Well, the memory used is negligible, but the number of drawing commands to the canvas context is going up with every frame. I think that drawing a couple thousand line segments is less efficient than drawing a few curves, but I can't say I've run the tests.

Comment: Ah so you mean it redraws each line segment for each frame??

Comment: Yes, on each frame there is a complete redraw, unless you specify some other way

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense! Explains why memory is small but CPU goes up and frame rate drops

Comment: Ok I've reaccepted the answer. My problem of the tab crashing was because i had set `MAX_SEGMENTS` too low and so sometimes too large a chunk of the path would get removed, meaning that there was no more `path` to be removed and so paperjs would throw a fit. Setting `MAX_SEGMENTS` to a decent length means that this won't happen.